# Adding a css file to a custom theme

Tags: theming

I'm a very beginner in drupal and I just want to add a css file to my custom theme.

So I created a `upjv.libraries.yml` in `themes/upjv` and I added :

```
global-styling:
version: '8.4.4'
css:
   theme:
       css/styles-upjv.css: {}
```

And I have created a `styles-upjv.css` in `themes/upjv/css`. On my index page, my file isn't loaded and I don't know if it's because I created the file in a wrong place, if the content of my libraries.yml is correct. Can anyone help me on this little problem please ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the following in your `upjv.info.yml`:

```
libraries: 
  - upjv/global-styling
```

Make sure to clear cache after that by navigating to `configuration > Development > Performance` then clicking on `Clear all caches` under `CLEAR CACHE`.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I added it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Do I have to add something in the backend ? Is there any log managed by drupal ?

Comment: Did you clear caches? I added the details on how to do that. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) on drupal.org.